# MSAccess Minimize Main DB Window with Modal Popup Form Open

Tags: ms-access, minimize, ms-access-2016

When launching the *.accdb, the modal popup form is opened and maximized. When the form is minimized, the main DB window can be seen in the background:

[image]

Is it possible to minimize the main DB window when the modal popup form is minimized, so that it does not show the main DB window at all.

I have tried the code below. However, it throws an error saying "Cannot minimize Access With XXX form On Screen".

Can anyone help?

Update: If I set the form to Modal: No, it works properly. The Main DB window is minimized to the taskbar. However, if I click on the icon in the taskbar, it opens up the Popup form again, with the Main DB window in the background. Is it possible to minimize the Main DB window to the notification area?

```
Option Compare Database 
Option Explicit 

Global Const SW_HIDE = 0 
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1 
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2 
Global Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3 

Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" _ 
Alias "ShowWindow" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _ 
ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long 

Function fSetAccessWindow(nCmdShow As Long) 

    Dim loX As Long 
    Dim loForm As Form 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set loForm = Screen.ActiveForm 

    If Err <> 0 Then 
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow) 
        Err.Clear 
    End If 

    If nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED And loForm.Modal = True Then 
        MsgBox "Cannot minimize Access with " _ 
        & (loForm.Caption + " ") _ 
        & "form on screen" 
    ElseIf nCmdShow = SW_HIDE And loForm.PopUp <> True Then 
        MsgBox "Cannot hide Access with " _ 
        & (loForm.Caption + " ") _ 
        & "form on screen" 
    Else 
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow) 
    End If 
    fSetAccessWindow = (loX <> 0) 
End Function
```

This is the On Load event.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call fSetAccessWindow(SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use this on load event

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call fSetAccessWindow(2)
End Sub
```